# OpenMP: conditional loop inside a parallel region

Tags: multithreading, if-statement, fortran, openmp

I've got a set of severak for-loops of which one is only executed if a certain condition is met.

How do I ensure that only one thread (maybe using `SINGLE`) executes the if-statement, but all threads are available for the `DO`.

```
!$omp parallel
!$omp do
do i=0,512
    something to do
end do
!$omp end do nowait

if (condition_var) then
    !$omp do
    do i=0,512
         only do sometimes
    end do
    !$omp end do
fi
!$omp end parallel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to ensure that only one thread evaluates the if condition, as long as the condition gives the *same result* among the threads in the team. To be more explicit:

```
!$omp parallel
!$omp do
do i=0,512
    something to do
end do
!$omp end do
! Synchronize here to ensure shared variables 
! will not be changed while evaluating the if condition

if (condition_var) then
! All threads evaluate the if condition and either enter
! the block or skip it
    !$omp do
    do i=0,512
         only do sometimes
    end do
    !$omp end do
fi
!$omp end parallel
```

Comment: Is the synchronization after the first loop required if the condition_var is not changed inside the parallel region?

Comment: @John No. The only thing you must ensure is that either _all the threads_ evaluate the `if` condition true or all evaluate it false.